# I want to show attendance with absent present status including week offs?

Tags: sql-server

I want to show the employee attendance with their present remark and show absent if the employee is absent for that particular date and also want to show saturday sunday as week off.

```
empid   empname Date        attendance
MT1020  Abc     2020-03-31  P
MT1020  Abc     2020-04-01  P
MT1020  Abc     2020-04-02  P
MT1020  Abc     2020-04-03  A
MT1020  Abc     2020-04-04  P
MT1020  Abc     2020-04-05  A
MT1020  Abc     2020-04-06  P
MT1020  Abc     2020-04-07  A
MT1020  Abc     2020-04-09  A
```

i want like this but including week off.

Comment: Please show us the result that you would expect for this sample data.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a calendar table (real or a tally) and then join it with your data to get the missing dates.